# Adobe Reader IE8 plugin fails with blank dialog

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, adobe-reader

In Windows 7, when Abode Reader plugin attempts to open web documents in IE8, sometimes a blank dialog box appears and the document fails to open. This issue has been discussed on other forums, e.g., [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproappcompat/thread/091e2e7e-4719-4076-aa6f-55dd5a26e5aa), but no specific solution is given. Reinstalling Reader does not seem to be a solution.

Comment: Which version of Reader are you trying to use?

Comment: This has been with multiple versions, right now I'm seeing the problem with 9.1.0.

Comment: Any reason not to try version 10 (Adobe Reader X)?

Comment: Agree with techie, you should upgrade if for no other reason than to take advantage of the security patches (there's still a 9.4.n iteration out there if you don't want to go all the way to 10)

Comment: Trying ver 10 ...

Comment: @techie007, version 10 seems to have solved the problem.